# Checking an SKNode is onscreen and visible

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, sknode

Is there a way to check when a `SKSpriteNode` / `SKNode` is onscreen (i.e. visible) I have a large scrolling background where I am spawning mobs, but I want to limit their animations and sounds if they are not visible. Is there a way to do this, I could write something in the update loop but I wanted to see if there was anything I could test before I start querying mob positions every frame?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid checking each sprite's position from the update method to see if they are in the screen maybe like this CGRectContainsRect([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds], yourSprite.frame)? Is it the update method that is causing the scrolling background to move?

Comment: Checking position of the node is the only way I know to achieve that

Comment: Did you find a better way than checking each frame bounds in the update method? Since the SpriteKit documentation says that nodes outside of the scene's visible area "are ignored by the renderer" I was hoping we could more easily enumerate those nodes somehow?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no mechanism in the SDK currently to quickly access nodes that are either on-screen or off-screen. The only way I know is to loop through all the nodes in the scene and check their positions one by one. Maybe WWDC 2014 next week will change this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this wrong. You should stick to the MVC pattern. As such, you only have data/points that are moving in a large area and in update method, if any data is within screen area, only would you draw them. If it is out, remove them.